# IBAction from TableViewCell triggers multiple cells

Tags: ios, uitableview, ibaction

I have a `UITableViewController` with dynamic cells.

in my `tableViewCellForRowAtIndexPath` I set the `indexPath.row` as tag to one of my subviews from that cell. This subview has an IBAction when one clicks on it.

In my custom `TableViewCell` I call a listener when this subview is clicked and give the value of the `tag` as parameter, so that my TableViewController can act on it.

This is what I do then: (it is in java, because I am using multi-os-engine but it is very similar to swift/obj-c)

```
@Override
    public void onOrderClicked(long index) {
        OrdersTableViewCell cell = (OrdersTableViewCell) ordersList().cellForRowAtIndexPath(NSIndexPath.indexPathForRowInSection(index, 0));

        if (cell.arrowView().image().equals(UIImage.imageNamed("downarrow"))) {
            cell.arrowView().setImage(UIImage.imageNamed("uparrow"));
            cell.orderDetailsView().setHidden(false);
        }
        else {
            cell.arrowView().setImage(UIImage.imageNamed("downarrow"));
            cell.orderDetailsView().setHidden(true);
        }
```

Basically I just change the hidden state of one subview in my cell. Actually this works fine. **BUT** when clicking on one of my elements, the subview hidden state sometimes changes not only from this cell, but also from another one. I don't understand why. For more information: There are multiple cells so, that I even have to scroll to see them all. And when clicking on one of my cells, the hidden state of another cell changes too, which is not in the screen atm.

Anyone has a hint what I am doing wrong or why this is happening?

Comment: If you are using custom tableViewCell subclass then you can write a custom delegate method and pass the cell with that method from your cell subclass to your tableViewController and inside the method you can get the indexPath using `tableView.indexPath(for: cell)`. assigning tags is a bad practice IMO.

Comment: That's because cells in tableViews (and collectionViews) are reused. This is a core concept and the reason behind good performance in lists. Instead of that, you should keep somewhere the desired states, reload the tableView (or the cells that need to change) and apply those changes for every cell in datasource methods.

Comment: @Alladinian ohhh yes this makes so much sense. Is there any possibility to disable the reusing? As I won't have many items in my tableview so I shouldn't have performance issues.

Comment: I would advise you against that, but you could return a different `reuseIdentifier` for each cell I guess...

Comment: @Alladinian what would be your approach to achieve my goal? Use uiview/stackviews intead of tableview? And I am not sure how to specify the reuseidentifier, as I set one in xcode.

Comment: Performance-wise tableView is the best choice (for the reason I mentioned). It's also pretty easy to use. If you got repeating content then use it. You _could_ use a stackView but it would only make sense if you got a handful of views _and_ you want something that would manage autolayout constraints for them (something like a form for example). Finally, think of cell state management like this: You do not _set_ the state _on_ cells, you _get_ the state _for_ cells...

Comment: The hidden/unbidden state should be kept in some other data structure or in your data model itself. You can then use that in `cellForRowAt` to configure the cell appropriately.

Comment: @Paulw11 ohh I should have thought about that. This fixed it!

Comment: @Paulw11 could you write an answer for this, so I can accept it?